# Notepad2 or similar editing tools for Mac?

Tags: macos, ide, text-editor

I am switching to a Mac web development environment (esp. Python and Javascript) after using a PC for many years.  On the PC, I used Notepad2 for most of my development; a really great minimal drop-in replacement for notepad. It has a very short install and setup process. I did not want code folding, I did not want a tabbed/multi document interface, and I think this lighter editing philosophy works well with interpreted languages. Notepad2 does syntax highlighting and powerful text operations well, plenty of sexy keyboard shortcuts.

Based on this, what kind of editor would you recommend for Mac? I am looking into TextEdit, Textwrangler, and PyCharm so far. Or should I man up and Vim?

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend **TextWrangler**. Although I was not his best friend at start I just love him now. Very powerful while (at the same time) straight forward and simple. When looking into Vim give **MacVim** a try (GVim for Mac). If provides a GUI granting you the possibility to keep basic text editor usage pattern like copy&paste (cmd-c cmd-v ...). Comfortable especially when using other ('regular') text editors in parallel.
I'm frequently using both of them.

Answer (score 1):

I use TextEdit on Mac, but I use Vim when I'm in the terminal on Mac.  So I'd say do both.  Checkout Playterm.org, they have some great Vim tutorials on there.

Textwrangler is okay, but I've found that the RegEx support/usability in TextEdit is superior.  That's just me.

I haven't used PyCharm, so I cannot say.  As far as Vim goes, it's a tool, and it does take time to learn how to use.  That being said, you can use it cross-platform and have access to all of the extras for it.  It's also free, whereas TextMate isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I will put in a vote for Sublime Text 2. Very powerful, fast, and extensible.

Comment: Yeah, it's some years later now, but I've been using Sublime Text.